# how to find area of foreground extracted using grabcut opencv

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I performed a foreground extraction using grabcut on an image. Now, I want to calculate the area of the resulted foreground portion of image.

One way i thought i could do this is by thresholding image, that is foreground becomes white and background becomes black. And then by calculating the number of white pixels -

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

rect = (1200,1050,1950,1250)

#applying grabcut
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

#thresholding
cvimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(cvimg,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

count = cv2.countNonZero(thresh)

print("White " , count)

cv2.imshow("image",thresh)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

But i doubt the accuracy as no. of pixels change when resolution of image changes. How can i find the area of foreground of images with a common unit of measurement for all images? Is there any other simple and appropriate method exists?

Thanks for helping...

Comment: Do you want the number of white pixels divided by the total amount of pixels, i.e. what percentage of an image is white?

Comment: but total number of pixels will change as the resolution of the image changes.... Different images with different resolution will have different no. of pixels.... Can we covert the resolution of image? So no matter what resolution an image has, we will be converting it into fixed resolution and each image will then have same resolution. But can we convert resolution using opencv?  @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: What I meant is: Let's say you have one image A, which has 100 x 100 = 10000 pixels and another one, image B, which has 200 x 200 = 40000 pixels. If you count the number of white pixels in each, let's say image A has 5000 white pixels and image B has 20000 white pixels, they both have 50% white pixels, meaning half of the image area is white. Not sure if this is what you want though.

Comment: Amazing @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you are genius.... Thanks a lot for explaining.... Thats exactly what i was looking for....i did not get it 1st time but it got clear as u explained it....thanks again....